# Visual Studio 2015 added files not being added to source control automatically in release branch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfvc

We have noticed in Visual Studio 2015 since Update 3 that any files or projects that get added to our solution no longer get picked up by source control (TFS) automatically:

[Image of solution explorer showing missing "+" sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcA0I.png)

When we right click the Person.cs file and select "Add files to Source Control" we get the following dialog:

[Image of source control dialog when trying to add file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIm6P.png)

I have seen some folks talk about using the .tfignore file to override this behavior but I have had no success at all with this approach.

Any help that can be provided would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known behavior and only occurs at **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3** for a branch with "*Release*" name. Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, everything is ok.

**Folders called *Release* and their contents is automatically excluded from TFS** (along with Debug and lots of file types). Just as your folks  suggested,  you could also **override** this for particular folders by creating a `.tfignore` file,  detail info please refer this link: [Customize which files are ignored by version control](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control)

> *Customize which files are ignored by version control*
>
> By default certain types of files (for example, .dll files) are
>   ignored by version control. As a result:
>
> When you add ignored files to folders that are mapped in a local
>   workspace, they do not appear in the Pending Changes page in Team
>   Explorer.
>
> When you try to add ignored files using the Add to Source Control
>   dialog box (for example by dragging them into Source Control
>   Explorer), they automatically appear in the Excluded items tab.
>
> You can configure which kinds of files are ignored by placing text
>   file called .tfignore in the folder where you want rules to apply. The
>   effects of the .tfignore file are recursive. **However, you can create
>   .tfignore files in sub-folders to override the effects of a .tfignore
>   file in a parent folder.**

The related .tfignore file rules may help you:

> .tfignore file rules
>
> `!` negates a filespec (files that match the pattern are not ignored)
>
> *For example:*
>
> Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
>  `!*.dll`

Comment: Do you know of a way to override the behavior under the entire "Release" branch with a single rule? I have tried "!\Release" in the top level .tfignore file but it had no effect. It seems unless I specify specific extensions like "!\Release\*.cs" nothing gets picked up.

Comment: @KenBrannigan No, it's not able to override **with a single rule**. You have to specific detail extensions. Or as a workaround , you could still use VS2015update2